# Is SQLite accessible from everywhere when an app is released?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm starting a new application in android studio with and I need a DataBase. I read that SQLite is the one that I need to use but I want to know if then when i publish my app the other people with their phones can acces this DataBase and where this DB is stored. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "other people with their phones"?

Comment: I recommend starting with some basic tutorials about app development

Comment: If a file is stored somewhere on the phone, then yes, someone will be able to read it, no matter what you do.

Comment: Users that use the application

Comment: `Is SQLite accessible from everywhere ... ?` **NO**. Only on the device where the app is installed. What you're looking for is a distributed RDBMS. Which, most likely lives on a server.

Comment: @Fantômas Which one do you reccomend me?

Comment: The one which fits your server architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite db is stored locally in phone memory. If you need public access to db you should use sql server with web service to access it.

Comment: And which ones do you recommend me?

Comment: It depends on your design, coding language, deployment target. There is no one way solution.

Comment: @AdriàSolé Do you need sql based database? If not, you may try mongoDB: https://www.mongodb.com/leading-nosql-database or Firebase: https://firebase.google.com. It depends on what sort of data you need to use in you application...

Answer (score 0):

NO. `SQLite` is just to store it on your phone, or laptop, or any local storage. Because it's easier to access a lot of information from a database than from a file, this is why `SQLite` was created.

So consider `SQLite` as a file, you store it locally, on your phone or you computer, to access the information in a nice way.

Although you can store `SQLite` on a server, it is not recommended, but instead database management systems like `MySQL` and `SQL Server` are used.

So for local storage, sqlite is a great technology to store your entries in an organized way, and you can execute queries like:

`select * from table` and `update table where id = 2`

just like you do in any other database management system (but locally this time of course).

Comment: And have the DB locally in a playstore application is a good idea? I mean it's going to occupy lot of space no?

Comment: it depends on what you want to hold in that db. keep in mind u can't access it from outside the local storage. so it's for the app only. one user can access only one sqlite db.

Comment: yes but if i use sql and then the people downloads the app all of them will have the DB in their phones. and if i want to update the database they only need to download the update from playstore right?

Comment: exactly! You should NOT be using sqlite for such.

Comment: And which one do you reccomend me?